# Send Email separately to all

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i am allowing user to enter multiple emails by comma separated . and i am taking those emails and sending them email all. want to send emails to Bcc.

i want to send them email separately , but [here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIn5A.png)

my PHP code is :

```
 $Email = new PHPMailer;
            $Email->IsSMTP(); 
            $Email->Host = "mail.cliqueipet.com.br"; 
            $Email->SMTPAuth = false; 
            $Email->IsHTML(true);
            $Email->Username = "xxxx"; 
            $Email->Password = "xxxx";
            $Email->SMTPSecure = "tls";
            //$Email->SMTPDebug = 2;
            $Email->From     = "convites@xxx.com.br";


            $Email->CharSet  = "UTF-8";
            $Email->FromName = $Nome . " - Festa na Vila das Pitangas";
     //here is i am adding address      
  for($i=0; $i<count($email); $i++):
                $Email->AddAddress($email[$i]);
            endfor; 
            $Email->Port = 587;
            $Email->Subject = " Convite para festa de $Nome na Vila das Pitangas. ";
```

Comment: Your screenshot is in different language. Can you explain in words what is wrong?

Comment: for loop is closed at the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `addBCC` function

Lets say that emails are saved as a string separated with ; from each other (you need to iterate through them and add each email to BCC with the `addBCC` function)

```
    $bcc_emails_str = "info@live.com;other@hotmail.com";

    $bcc_emails_array = explode(";", $bcc_emails_str);

    foreach($bcc_emails_array as $email)
    {
      if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
      {
        $mail->addBCC($email);
      }
    }
```

For further information read the [PHPMailer documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: PHPMailer validates addresses automatically when you add them, so there's no need to run `filter_var` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$toEmails = array('xyz@gmail.com','abc@gmail.com');    
for($i=0; $i<count($toEmails); $i++):
       $Email = new PHPMailer;
       $Email->IsSMTP(); 
       $Email->Host = "mail.cliqueipet.com.br"; 
       $Email->SMTPAuth = false; 
       $Email->IsHTML(true);
       $Email->Username = "xxxx"; 
       $Email->Password = "xxxx";
       $Email->SMTPSecure = "tls";
       //$Email->SMTPDebug = 2;
       $Email->From     = "convites@xxx.com.br";


       $Email->CharSet  = "UTF-8";
       $Email->FromName = $Nome . " - Festa na Vila das Pitangas";
       $mail->addAddress($toEmails[$i]);
       $mail->Subject  = 'Convite para festa de $Nome na Vila das Pitangas.';
       $mail->Body     = '<your mail body here>';
       if(!$mail->send()) {
              echo 'Message was not sent.';
              echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       } else {
              echo 'Message has been sent.';
       }
    endfor;  //this should end when ur first email sent 


    This should work will send 1 mail at a time in the loop.
```